# How can i access IServiceCollection from a background thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task

I am trying to perform some long running operations in the background. These operations would need access to some services that have been registered with ServiceCollection in Startup.cs.

I am injecting IServiceProvider to the class that is going to spawn a background thread.

```
public WorkflowService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
```

(*Note, i cannot inject individual services because i don't know before-hand which component is going to be invoked and which services each component will require*).

I am then passing _serviceProvider to the method that will be executed in the background.

```
Task task = new Task(() => ExecuteStep(firstStep, workflowInstanceId, workflowMetadata, _serviceProvider));
task.Start();
```

Ths issue is that by the time i try to resolve a service on the background thread, IServiceProvider has been disposed and i get an exception.

```
object service = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(item.GetType());
```

In ASP.NET 4.5, i could have achieved something similar by using GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver, but i am unable to find something equivalent in Core 2.2 or figure out the right way to achieve this.

```
using (var scope = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.BeginScope())
{

....
     //Obtain the Type from the DI container
     object service = scope.GetService(serviceType);
....
}
```

Comment: .net core has background services that support the DI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) for background tasks.

Anyway, you can create new scope with `IServiceScopeFactory`:

```
public WorkflowService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceProviderFactory)
{
    var scope = serviceProviderFactory.CreateScope();
    _serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
}
```